# Keep-Alive header not working as expected in Gunicorn with Python WSGI app

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have a Python WSGI app that I'm trying to run using Gunicorn. I tried to set up the "Connection: keep-alive" header in the response, but I'm still getting "Connection: Close" in the response headers. I'm unsure why the "keep-alive" connection is not maintained. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    """Simplest possible application object"""
    data = b'Hello, World!\n'
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [
        ('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
        ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(data)))
    ]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return iter([data])
```

Running gunicorn with command:
`gunicorn main:app`

I also tried this:
`gunicorn main:app --keep-alive 10`

When I make an HTTP Request I always get Connection close in the header.

Header response:
[Header response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A6vm.png)